# Published App on Play Store can't communicate with Google Calendar API

Tags: android, google-api, google-oauth

I have in hand my SHA1 key gotten from my keystore with the following command

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore path-to-debug-or-production-keystore -list -v
```

I've also made sure the package name in on my credentials page is the same as the one in the application id in build.gradle

I get the following exception thrown in my code: GoogleAuthIOException when trying to communicate from my app to the api. My code is the exact same code found here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android So I'm pretty sure I'm not doing anything wrong when it comes to setting up my service

What am I doing wrong? 
Thank you!

Comment: make sure the signature is the correct one, because google play can sign your app with their generated signature.

Comment: App signing certificate or the Upload certificate?

Comment: the signing certificate